# Probability advanced question with random variable and repeating.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is the task:

John is employed in the warehouse of an online clothing store. He got five orders for the same T-shirt
model and size. Two shirts must be red, two blue and one black. John
prepares five identical packages (one T-shirt in each), but forgets to mark them and now does not know
in which package is what color shirt. He decides to write all five addresses at random on
packets - each address to one packet. Let the random variable X measure the number of correct colors of shirts per
the right address. Write down the probability scheme of the random variable X. How much is expected
the number of right shirt colors at the right address?

I understand that the options for right color tshirts at right address are: {0,1,2,3,5}

I also understand that number of all possible arrangements is 30(because of repeating), otherwise would be 120.

I also understand that the probability of all tshirts on the right address is 1/30 or 4/120.

I would like to know how to calculate probability for other values(0,1,2,3 right shirts on right address)

The only thing confusing me is this repeating, i don't know how to deal with it.

In advance thank you for your responses!

Comment: You have six unknowns $P[X=i]$ for $i \in \{0, …, 5\}$. But you also know $P[X=5]=4/120$, $P[X=4]=0$, and all probabilities sum to 1. You can also compute $E[X]=9/5$. So you need two more equations.